# Passing multiple items from selectbox is not working in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel project, am showing select box which contains various clinics, each clinic have `api_key` and `id` . I want to pass both id and api_key to Laravel Controller when a form is submitted.
But now am getting only `api_key`  .ID is not getting.

Following is my code in view page

```
<form method="post"  action="{{ route('viewcode') }}" name="cliniclist" id="cliniclist" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
{{ csrf_field() }}
<select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-info btn-fill btn-block" id="clinic_id" name="clinic_id" key="clinic_key">
         @foreach($clinics as$clinic)
            <option value="{!! $clinic->api_key !!}" id="{!! $clinic->api_key !!}" clinic_key="{!! $clinic->clinicID !!}">{!! $clinic->clinicName !!}</option>
         @endforeach
 </select>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 form-action">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-info">Submit</button>
          <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-fill">Cancel</a> 
 </div>

</form>
```

Here in my code am printing clinic id in `clinic_key` attribute

Following is my code in controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    echo $request->clinic_key;
    die();
    $clinic_api_key = $request->clinic_id;
    return view('locations.viewcode')->with(['clinic_api' => $clinic_api_key]);
}
```

What is the problem here

Comment: There's no element with `name="clinic_key"` in your form. If you want to submit two values within one `<option>` element you could use something like `<option value="{!! $clinic->api_key !!}_{!! $clinic->key !!}">` and parse the value (split by `_`) in your controller. Or use Ajax to assemble the data and submit

Comment: Can you please post it as answer, with codes

Answer (score 1):

**You can do it simply like**

```
<option value="{!! $clinic->api_key.'-'.$clinic->id !!}">{!! $clinic->clinicName !!}</option>
```

And inside controller do it this way

```
$split = explode("-",$request->clinic_id);
$clinic_api_key = $split[0];
$clinic_id = $split[1];
```

> Updated Answer. With little jquery you can do in this way.

```
<form method="post"  action="{{ route('viewcode') }}" name="cliniclist" id="cliniclist" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-info btn-fill btn-block" id="clinic_id" name="clinic_id" key="clinic_key">
                @foreach($clinics as$clinic)
                    <option value="{!! $clinic->api_key !!}" data-clinic_id="{!! $clinic->clinicID !!}">{!! $clinic->clinicName !!}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
            <input type="hidden" name="api_key" id="api_key">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id">

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 form-action">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-info">Submit</button>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-fill">Cancel</a>
            </div>

        </form>
```

**Jquery Code, as you can see i have placed two hidden inputs inside your form, so you will access these two inputs inside your controller except select name.**

```
$(document).on('change','#clinic_id',function(){
            var clinic_api_key = $('option:selected',this).val();
            var clinic_id = $('option:selected',this).data('clinic_id');

            $("#api_key").val(clinic_api_key);
            $("#id").val(clinic_id);
        });
```

**Now in controller**

```
$request->api_key;
$request->id;
```

Comment: What if `$clinic->api_key` (or `$clinic->id`) contains a `-`?

Comment: Then you can use some other pattern just for uniqueness like `$$` or `///` etc.. and then use `explode('///',$variable);`

Answer (score 1):

Option tag can have only one value. Since you are trying to get 2 values there, you might want to join them with some special characters like hyphen "-" or maybe colon ":". In that way you can separate them by that special character in our controller later.

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-info btn-fill btn-block" id="clinic_id" name="clinic_id" key="clinic_key">
@foreach($clinics as$clinic)
<option value="{!! $clinic->api_key.'-'.$clinic->id !!}" id="{!! $clinic->api_key !!}" clinic_key="{!! $clinic->clinicID !!}">{!! $clinic->clinicName !!}</option>
@endforeach
 </select>
```

And then in your controller just get the value of clinic_id field and separate them.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //make sure clinic_id and id does not contain '-' in their values
        $clinic_data = explode('-',$request->clinic_id);
        $clinic_id = $clinic_data[1];
        $clinic_api_key = $clinic_data[0];
        return view('locations.viewcode',compact('clinic_id','clinic_api_key'));

    }
```

for the above code to work. please make sure your api_key and id data from the database does not contain "-" or will break. In that case, use some other separator.

Comment: Please don't copy someone's answer.

Comment: It is producing this error The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.